# Android SDK. Send data over Satellite/GPS

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-networking

I have an off-road application primarily used by off-road riders and walkers to find trails traveled by others.

App Example can be found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wmk3cA2i2vI

As standard, data can be sent over wifi or the cell towers, which is controlled by the Android OS.

Because you can move from wifi network to wifi network, to cell towers, users of my app will get a huge delay as the phone disconnects and connects to another network.

What I want to know is if I can also send data over the GPS/Satellite network when I choose by setting a "cell state" option or something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far i know you can't send data through GPS, GPS don't provide data sending.You can actually use only internet connection either wifi, GPRS or WAP to send data.

Answer (score 0):

No.  NOBODY can send data over GPS satellites, not even the U. S. Air Force, who owns them.  That's not what they do.

There are satellite communication systems (see inmarsat, globalstar, iridium).  NONE of these can be used by standard android phones.  Phones on these systems are generally much larger and way more expensive than standard smartphones.